# Exact solution to the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation for a massless scalar field

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, cosmology

I am reading some cosmology review papers and I am at the section in which the equation of motion for a massless scalar field in a de Sitter spacetime is derived. The equation of motion for the fourier mode is given,

$f_k'' + (k^2 - \frac{a''}{a})f_k = 0$

In de Sitter spacetime $\frac{a''}{a} = - \frac{2}{\tau^2}$ and the eom becomes,

$f_k'' + (k^2 - \frac{2}{\tau^2})f_k = 0$

It is stated that the solution is of the form

$f_k = \alpha e^{-ik\tau}(1-\frac{i}{k \tau}) + \beta e^{ik\tau}(1+\frac{i}{k\tau})$

I am trying to figure out how this solution is obtained. Would anyone be able to help me with this?